# How to set VM operating system to update automatically when creating using an ARM template - Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I've built a VM in Azure using Powershell commands and an ARM template.  My template has this section:

```
             "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_abc_name')]",
                    "adminUsername": "testadm",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "provisionVMAgent": true,
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
                    },
                    "secrets": [],
                    "allowExtensionOperations": true
                },
```

You can see I've set "enableAutomaticUpates" to true.  BUT when the machine is provisioned, it's not enabled.  Anyone seen this issue before?  Is there an equivalent Powershell command I can run on a specific VM?  My VM is Windows Datacentre OS.

Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Comment: You can try the custom vm extension with a PowerShell script in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always created VM with that option and never had any issues. Do you have something that indicates Windows update was not enabled after using that option?

But as far as Powershell equivalent;

`Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmoperatingsystem?view=azurermps-6.11.0

Answer (score 1):

This looks syntactically correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json

I've never seen this being used though, only various solutions, like Azure Automation\Log Analytics